# C++. How to design inheritance of BST in AVL-Tree

Tags: c++, inheritance, data-structures, binary-tree, avl-tree

I'm wondering how to properly implement the AVL tree based on the existing binary search tree.

There is a template Node class that stores the key and node-data (like dictionary), pointers to subtrees.

```
template <class T>
class Node
{
private:
    T _data;
    int _key;
    Node* _left, * _right;

public:
    friend class BinaryTree<T>;
}
```

The template class Tree stores a pointer to the root and invariants of the tree.

```
template <class T>
class BinaryTree
{
private:
    Node<T>* _root;
    int _height,
        _order;
}
```

So, I would like to inherit this tree by simply overriding adding, deleting (by making functions virtual). And it's obviously - AVL is binary tree, with the only difference - it is always balanced.

But there is a problem - the Node class. For the AVL it should contain a height relative to the root, for the BST it is unnecessary, and I don't know how to resolve this collision without workarounds.

Comment: [Cross-site dupe on ruSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1516687/215103). What's wrong with the CRTP-based approach I suggested there?

Comment: *"For the AVL it should contain a height relative to the root"*: does it? As far as I know, you only need a balance factor that can be -1, 0 or 1.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat everything is okay, but I wanted to have some feedback from foreign language forum, maybe smb knows anything that exactly helps me

Comment: @trincot yes, height is known -> bfactor is known in linear operation

Comment: Yes, but AVL algorithm is designed to do this without height.

Comment: It’s never mind. They are equal. But the main question is not resolved

Answer (score 1):

Your `BinaryTree` class allows you to associate arbitrary data with each node, so just use that:

```
template<class T>
class AvlTree<T> : BinaryTree<std::pair<T,int>> {
 ...
}
```

Comment: I think it is workaround, because of syntax: height pole has appeal like tree.data.first. And data-getter method won’t work well

Comment: Yes, that's true.  Once methods are added to the BinaryTree base class, it will probably become clear that delegation should be used instead of inheritance.  If the tree's nodes are also exposed, then best just to make a separate implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Of all the evils, I chose the least: I added a default parameter to the template that accepts the node type, in the body of the class, I replaced the old Node types with the template type:

```
template <typename T, class TypeNode = Node<T>>
class BinaryTree{
    ...
    BinaryTree(BinaryTree<T, TypeNode>&& other) noexcept;
    ...
    TypeNode* find(int) const;
    ...
};
```

At the same time, the initialization remained the same as was:

```
BinaryTree<int> tree(key, data, 16); // 16 - size of arrays key & data
```

For the AVL tree, I wrote my own node container (minimum code duplication):

```
template <typename T>
class AVLNode
{
public:
    T _data;
    int _key;
    AVLNode* _left, * _right;
    int _height;

public:
    friend class AVLTree<T>;        
    ...
}
```

Well, inherited the tree itself, substituting AVLNode as a container:

```
template <typename T, class TypeNode>
class AVLTree : public BinaryTree<T, AVLNode<T>>
{
public:
    AVLTree() : BinaryTree<T, AVLNode<T>>() {
    }
    ...
}
```

**For refining the solution, you need to inherit the AVL node itself. I faced the following problem:**

```
template <typename T>
class AVLNode : public Node<T> 
{
protected:
    int _height;

public:
    friend class AVLTree<T>;
    ...
};
```

with this structure, the node pointers still remain not avl, so there are two options:

1. to make them private, add them to both AVL and BST with the right type - duplication of code, what the reason for inheritance then?
2. to make the same template parameter for the node as for BST, but then the question arises with the default parameter: it will be a class whose template parameter it is - compilation error. how to resolve is is a question.